# Prolog - Multiples of a Number Below an Upper Limit

Tags: prolog

I am currently making a program in Prolog that will calculate all of the multiples (including itself) of a number, that do not exceed the value of another number. I was testing with the query below:

```
    ?- multiples(4,12,R,0)
```

This query would list all multiples of 4 that are less than or equal to 12 eg. 4, 8, 12. The R would return the result and 0 is where I was intending to implement a counter that would count up for each multiplication eg. 4*1,4*2,4*3. I am stuck and I am not sure if it would be a better design to simply add the multiples and check if it is below the upper bound or if it can be done with a counter or accumulator.

```
multiples(N,U,R,Ctr) :-
        N =< U,
        R is Ctr * N,
        R =< U,
        increment(Ctr,Ctr2),
        multiples(N,U,R,Ctr2).

increment(Num, Num1) :-
        Num1 is Num+1.
```

I believe my program is failing at the recursive step of calling multiples from within itself. I know that recursion needs a base case to allow it to exit, but I am completely stuck here and would appreciate some direction.

Comment: You do not need to check `N =< U`, and `Ctrl` should start with 1 I think.

Comment: Furthermore here `R` will **never** be unified. This will always lead to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with you approach is that **there is no basecase**: indeed your algorithm will always produce `false.` It will unify `R` with `N`, then do the recursion and that recursion will try to unify `R` with `2*N` which will fail.

Well an idea could be to use an accumulator *to which you add the delta each time*. Something like:

```
multiples(N,U,R) :-
    multiples(N,N,U,R).

multiples(_,C,U,C) :-
    C =< U.
multiples(N,C,U,R) :-
    C =< U,
    C1 is C+N,
    multiples(N,C1,U,R).
```

So here we call `multiples(3,12,R).` and it will result in:

```
?- multiples(4,12,R).
R = 4 ;
R = 8 ;
R = 12 ;
false.
```

Answer (score 1):

CLP(FD) is very helpful here:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

multiple(Multiplicand, Max, Multiple) :-
    MaxMultiplier #= Max // Multiplicand,
    label([MaxMultiplier]),
    Multiplier in 1 .. MaxMultiplier,
    Multiple #= Multiplier * Multiplicand,
    label([Multiple]).

?- multiple(4, 12, M).
M = 4 ;
M = 8 ;
M = 12.

?-
```

With CLP(FD) in this case, you can also query with the first argument as a variable:

```
|?- multiple(N, 12, 8).
N = 8 ;
N = 4 ;
N = 2 ;
N = 1.
```

Or both the multiplier and result:

```
?- multiple(N, 4, M).
N = M, M = 3 ;
N = M, M = 4 ;
N = M, M = 2 ;
N = 2,
M = 4 ;
N = M, M = 1 ;
N = 1,
M = 2 ;
N = 1,
M = 3 ;
N = 1,
M = 4.

?-
```

If you want to collect them in a list, you can use `findall/3`:

```
?- findall(Multiple, multiple(4, 12, Multiple), Multiples).
Multiples = [4, 8, 12].

?-
```