# Prolog methods not calling base case

Tags: prolog

I am trying to build a program that takes two integers (for example, 4 and 15) and returns the multiples of the first integer that divide into the second integer.

My program is as follows:

```
divisible(D,U,X):-
   divisible_ext(D,U,D,X).

divisible_ext(D,U,D,X):-
   U < D,
   !.
divisible_ext(D,U,S,X):-
   U > D,
   D1 is D + S,
   divisible_ext(D1,U,S,X1),
   X is D.
```

As far as I am aware, my program should fail the base case with each call until the D value is greater than U (so with 4 and 15, 16 > 15). However in the trace, I can see that the base case is only called the first time, and then never again. Thus when D = 16, the `U > D` call fails and the entire program fails.

Why is the base case only being called once? Is there something I am not understanding about Prolog that I need to know, or is there a change to my code that I should make?

Edit: Here is my trace:

```
[trace] 20 ?- divisible(4,15,X).
   Call: (7) divisible(4, 15, _G9543) ? creep
   Call: (8) divisible_ext(4, 15, 4, _G9543) ? creep
   Call: (9) 15<4 ? creep
   Fail: (9) 15<4 ? creep
   Redo: (8) divisible_ext(4, 15, 4, _G9543) ? creep
   Call: (9) 15>4 ? creep
   Exit: (9) 15>4 ? creep
   Call: (9) _G9622 is 4+4 ? creep
   Exit: (9) 8 is 4+4 ? creep
   Call: (9) divisible_ext(8, 15, 4, _G9625) ? creep
   Call: (10) 15>8 ? creep
   Exit: (10) 15>8 ? creep
   Call: (10) _G9625 is 8+4 ? creep
   Exit: (10) 12 is 8+4 ? creep
   Call: (10) divisible_ext(12, 15, 4, _G9628) ? creep
   Call: (11) 15>12 ? creep
   Exit: (11) 15>12 ? creep
   Call: (11) _G9628 is 12+4 ? creep
   Exit: (11) 16 is 12+4 ? creep
   Call: (11) divisible_ext(16, 15, 4, _G9631) ? creep
   Call: (12) 15>16 ? creep
   Fail: (12) 15>16 ? creep
   Fail: (11) divisible_ext(16, 15, 4, _G9631) ? creep
   Fail: (10) divisible_ext(12, 15, 4, _G9628) ? creep
   Fail: (9) divisible_ext(8, 15, 4, _G9625) ? creep
   Fail: (8) divisible_ext(4, 15, 4, _G9543) ? creep
   Fail: (7) divisible(4, 15, _G9543) ? creep
false.
```

Comment: maybe missing the U==D case ?

Comment: Homework? See: [Prolog - Multiples of a Number Below an Upper Limit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42447078/1243762)

Comment: @GuyCoder thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is the base case only being called once?

The base case is

```
divisible_ext(D,U,D,X) :-
```

and the other case is

```
 divisible_ext(D,U,S,X) :-
```

Notice that on the first call

```
Call: (8) divisible_ext(4, 15, 4, _G9543) ? creep
          divisible_ext(D,  U, D,     X) :-                 <-- Base case
          divisible_ext(D,  U, S,     X) :-                 <-- Other case
```

For the base case  `D = 4` for both `D` and
for the other case `D = 4` and `S = 4`
so both predicates can be called.

Notice on the second call

```
Call: (9) divisible_ext(8, 15, 4, _G9625) ? creep
          divisible_ext(D,  U, D,      X) :-                 <-- Base case
          divisible_ext(D,  U, S,      X) :-                 <-- Other case
```

For the base case  `D = 8` and `D = 4` and
for the other case `D = 4` and `S = 4`
so the base can not be called because the first `D` is now `8` and second `D` is `4` which means the [unification](http://www.amzi.com/AdventureInProlog/a10unif.php) will not work and thus the predicate can not be called.

Comment: Oh, duh. Okay thanks very much, I don't know why I didn't see that before.